# Too late to get Windows 10 10240?

Tags: windows-10-preview, windows-10-upgrade

I just (July 19) installed Windows 10 build 10130.  I got a few updates, but it's not picking up the 10240 build. Is it too late?

Comment: No?  You have to link your local account to a Microsoft Account.  The only way to get build 10240 currently is through the Windows Update system.

Comment: There are .isos made from the ESD files best to determine the reason its not showing up in your installation though.  Be sure to write down your current license key, since if its changed, you won't be able to activate it.

Comment: There is a hold on the activation service until Win10 goes live - if you can't activate, you can't get updates at the moment, as it won't even verify that you're on the Insider program. You'll have to wait until next Weds, 29th, when it comes back up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might as well make this an answer - it will all be moot come July 29th anyway…

There is a hold on the activation service until Win10 goes live - if you can't activate, you can't get updates at the moment, as it won't even verify that you're on the Insider program. You'll have to wait until next Weds, 29th, when it comes back up.